# Mysql YEAR how to set the current year as default value

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table with a PK column with the current year

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example` (
  `yearId` YEAR NOT NULL DEFAULT year(curdate()),
  PRIMARY KEY (`yearId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

But it is not correct.

I know that I can save the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example` (
  `yearId` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`yearId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

But I only want the year.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `YEAR()` function and pass that value to it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example` (
  `yearId` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  PRIMARY KEY (`yearId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

[Click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more date and time functions.

P.S. You should probably set the data type for that column to `YEAR(4)` to ensure that only valid values for a year are entered.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),    PRIMARY KEY (`yearId`)) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 2

Comment: Check the documentation for YEAR(). You may not be able to use the TIMESTAMP data type when using it.

Comment: I'm using YEAR and throws me the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use functions as a default value.